# Stripe Charge promise doesn't resolve

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, stripe-payments

I'm making an AJAX call from `StripeCheckout.configure({ })` on the `token` parameter, like this:

```
StripeCheckout.configure({
  ...,
  token: function(stripeToken) {
    $.post( url, {
      // post data
    }, function(data) {
      console.log("data", data);
      return data;
    });
  }
});
```

At the URL which receives the AJAX call (let's call it `/charge`), I have this code:

```
const charge = (req, res) => {
  const {
    // get AJAX post data, e.g amount, description, STRIPE_TOKEN, etc
  } = req.body 
  return stripe.charges.create({
    amount: amount,
    currency: 'gbp',
    source: STRIPE_TOKEN,
    description: description,
  })
  .then((charge) => {
    const {params} = charge // get various parameters from the successful charge data to be passed into book()
    return book(params) // promise function which goes to an external provider
    .then((data) => {
      return data // data returns from book and is then lost between here and the original AJAX callback 
    })
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

as you can see from the comments, the `data` in the charge function is correct, but then between that promise and the original AJAX call, it's lost and the AJAX call gets nothing. If I look at the network request in Chrome devtools, it says that `charge` received the data but the AJAX call times out as it receives no response data.

I think I've been looking at this too long and have probably made a super easy and stupid mistake.

Comment: a) you don't `return` the `book(…)` promise from the `then` callback b) where are you  writing the response???

Comment: Hi @Bergi, thanks I added that return in. I also realised I forgot to add a `console.log` to the AJAX call to write the returned data (had it in my code but not here on SO). However, with those two additions it's still not returning anything :(

Comment: `console.log` writes to the console, not to the HTTP response. You probably need something like `res.json(data)` (but I don't know the Stripe API)

Comment: hi @Bergi, thanks! `res.json(data)` instead of `return data` in the `charge` promise works! I'd be happy to accept this as the correct answer if you want to write it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out with help from @Bergi in the comments (thanks Bergi!).

Here is the code that worked for me, sending the update from the promise back to the original Ajax request:

```
const charge = (req, res) => {
    // rest of the promise
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data) 
    })
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

The reason for this is essentially, the AJAX request is hitting the page (`/charge` in my case), doing the work to get the data, but returning it does nothing, as, just like in a front-end app, unless you are doing something with it (assigning to a variable, running another function with that data, etc), it will get lost. It needs to be outputted to the page, in JSON format, so the request can see it.